# Using chunks of MP4 file for thumbnails

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4

I want to extract single frames (as thumbs) from videos, without having to download the full video file. I would like to just read the mp4 header (the info should be in the moov atom) and then download the required byte ranges. Afaik thats what browsers (HTML5 video) do when you skip to an unbuffered part

I already looked at: [How can HTML5 video's byte-range requests (pseudo-streaming) work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18178374/how-can-html5-videos-byte-range-requests-pseudo-streaming-work) but i can't figure out how to use it with ffmpeg for example.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's how a general algorithm might operate if you were absolutely determined to make this approach work:

- download the first kilobyte of the MP4 file
- make sure the `moov` atom is up front; determine `moov` atom's length and make another request to fetch the rest of the atom
- dig through the `moov` atom to find the video `trak` atom; dig into that atom to find the following atoms: `stsd`, `stss`, `stco`/`co64`, and `stsz`
- the `stsd` will give you initialization information required to feed into the H.264 video decoder
- the `stss` atom gives you a list of all the sync samples (keyframes); these can be decoded independently and would be ideal for your thumbnailing prospects
- when you know which frames are keyframes, courtesy of the `stss` atom, you can cross reference with the `stco` or `co64` atoms (a `trak` will have one or the other) in order to find the absolute file location, and the `stsz` atom, which will tell you exactly how many bytes are in the frame

With all of this information combined, you should be able to download and decode (and thus resize and re-compress for thumbnailing) just the keyframes of an MP4 video.