# I cannot navigate(rewind) back/forward with html5 video when spring returns FileSystemResource

Tags: html, spring, http, spring-mvc, video.js

I am novice with html5 video. I chose the
http://www.videojs.com/

I can embed following player on my page and it works well when I use extrernal video link:

http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4

But when I stored following video on disk and wrote following spring controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/testVideo")
    @ResponseBody
    public  FileSystemResource testVideo(Principal principal) throws IOException {
        return new FileSystemResource(new File("D:\\oceans.mp4"));

    }
```

And replace external link with `/testVideo` I see that I cannot navigate back and forward.

What the problem(http headers are wrong?)? how to fix it?

Comment: answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28427339/how-to-implement-http-byte-range-requests-in-spring-mvc

Answer (score 1):

You need to support byte range requests rather than returning the whole file. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18179014/740233) for background but I can't speak to how you would implement that in Spring.

Comment: Can you help me to formulate question? I want to know how to implement it in spring.