# Reading bytes from a mp4 file based on a particular start time and end time.

Tags: video, mp4, mp4parser

Is it possible to read bytes from a .mp4 file that represent a specific timespan in the video ?

For example can I read the bytes that represent just the last 5 minutes of the video ?

The assumption is that the video is VBR encoded.

If yes is there an API that can help me do that ? I don't care what language it is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, and just about any mp4 library will do. Just google for one. The accual process is laid out here: [How can HTML5 video's byte-range requests (pseudo-streaming) work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18178374/how-can-html5-videos-byte-range-requests-pseudo-streaming-work)