# Web - Video : bytes range to time

Tags: php, http, video, range, byte

I have a PHP script for stream a video from an url, and I want to get the time to control the flow.

Browsers makes HTTP requests with a range of bytes when jumping at a time of the video.

**Request Headers**

```
Accept:*/ *
Accept-Encoding:identity;q=1, *;q=0
Accept-Language:fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Host:h.com
If-Range:Tue, 20 Oct 2015 23:38:00 GMT
Range:bytes=560855038-583155711
Referer:http://h.com/7743a76d2911cdd90354bc42be302c6946c6e5b4
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.75 Safari/537.36
```

**Response Headers**

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:private, max-age=14400
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:22300674
Content-Range:bytes 560855038-583155711/605162520
Content-Type:video/mp4
Date:Tue, 10 May 2016 11:23:34 GMT
Expires:Tue, 10 05 2016 15:23:34 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=98
Last-Modified:Tue, 20 Oct 2015 23:38:00 GMT
Server:Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.16
```

How works that time to bytes conversion ?

On my PHP server I try to get the time from the byte request :

```
$time_second = $start_request_byte / $video_size_byte * $video_length_second;
```

But it's not the solution, it isn't exact... Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: `Content-Range` is what the server sends. The browser sends `Range`. Are you building the server that must respond to browsers’ range requests? It’s not very clear.

Comment: What is used in the browser to display the video? An HTML `<video>` element? Can you show some code?

Comment: The filesize has no relation with the video length. I can make an 1 hour long video with a filesize of 5MB. But also a video which only lasts 1 minute but is 500MB big.

Comment: @VasiliyFaronov Yes, my bad, it's "range", not "Content-Range". And it's a simple `video` element for display the video.

Comment: @BrianNydegger That’s not a valid `Range` header. Can you show what the browser actually sends?

Comment: @VasiliyFaronov You're right. I confused the request and the response. I change my post with a complete example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can HTML5 video's byte-range requests (pseudo-streaming) work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18178374/how-can-html5-videos-byte-range-requests-pseudo-streaming-work)

Comment: This question has been ansered several times on stackoverlfow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18178374/how-can-html5-videos-byte-range-requests-pseudo-streaming-work

Comment: @szatmary Yes, but there is no solution for implementation. I'll post mine.

Comment: by the way these comments just link to another question that have a generic solution, that does not answer this question. In fact the right answer it is not to point to the documentation (googling it), it's about posting a solution with code, like the one below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution using ffprobe !

**Command**

```
$ ffprobe -i 430079256.mp4 -show_frames \
-show_entries frame=pkt_pos \
-read_intervals 01:23%+#1 \
-of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 \
-hide_banner -loglevel panic
```

**Output**

Offset byte => 1:23 of the video

```
209782270
```

**Explain**

- `-i 430079256.mp4` Video input
- `-show_frames` Display information about each frame
- `-show_entries frame=pkt_pos` Display only information about byte position
- `-read_intervals 01:23%+#1` Read only 1 packet after seeking to position 01:23
- `-of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1` Don't want to print the key
  and the section header and footer
- `-hide_banner -loglevel panic` Don't want to print banner of ffprob, and hide meta on with "panic" who only show fatal errors

Comment: Nice!!! So assumed I want to use this for `start` and `end` of a `Content-Range` header I have to do for both. I have the values in seconds, so first I have to convert to minutes, right to match the `read_intervals` format? Thank you.