# Convert Byte-range to Time-range in html <video>

Tags: javascript, html, ffmpeg

I have some sever-side code that currently supports the http byte range requests without an issue. However, I want to be able to transcode the video file (which is located on-disk) on-the-fly with ffmpeg before I send the transcoded chunk to the client, but ffmpeg requires I give it a seek time whereas I get byte ranges from the client. How would I be able to figure out the time range (seek time) of a video file given the byte range from the client browser?

I have already looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37134341/web-video-bytes-range-to-time) which assumes the server already knows the specified time.

I am open to using an html5 video player which supports the use of time ranges to request data instead of byte ranges, but I have been unable to find an implementation or figure out how the javascript side of buffering `<video>` works.

Comment: You can try [fetching](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#http)  the video with `offset` and `end_offset`

Comment: Those options seem to be only for http streaming directly with ffmpeg. I'm using ffmpeg to transcode only.

Comment: The commit which added those mention "request ranges".

Comment: Do you have a link to the commit? thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/2ec33d27127251bbc45e1f88e60691ad59cf2319

Comment: `$ ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -acodec copy -vcodec copy -offset <arbitrary number> -end_offset <arbitrary number> 2.mp4` gives back the entire video file unchanged, starting transcoding from the beginning to the end. The commit checks for and adds the `Range` header, which again tells me these options deal with ffmpeg's http output and not local file input/output.

Comment: Of course it does not deal with local file input. The commit applies to the http protocol, so the syntax is `ffmpeg -offset START -end_offset END -i http://source-url -c copy out.mp4` BTW, your command copies and doesn't transcode, so you may lose some frames at start.

Comment: The file I'm trying to transcode is located on-disk. I've updated the question wording to make that clearer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can run ffprobe and analyze its output to identify the timestamps.

Basic command is

```
ffprobe -i in.mp4 -show_entries packet=pos,pts_time,flags -select_streams v -of compact=p=0:nk=1 -v 0
```

This produces

```
0.000000|48|K_
0.133333|956|__
0.066667|996|__
0.033333|1053|__
0.100000|1602|__
0.266667|1811|__
0.200000|2371|__
0.166667|2746|__
0.233333|3294|__
....
```

The first column is the video frame timestamp, the 2nd is the byte offset for that frame and the 3rd is whether the frame is a keyframe.

Since you can only cut video at keyframes, when copying the stream, you will either have to cut at a timestamp whose flag is `K` or use the argument in the command below:

```
ffmpeg -ss X -i in.mp4 -c copy -avoid_negative_ts make_zero out.mp4
```

This is not needed if you're transcoding the video stream.